# Detect RabbitMQ broker failure/restart

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I am using Python consumers (long running, potentially hours) with manual acknowledgement. I am wondering what happens to unachnowldeged messages in case RabbitMQ broker fails, has been restarted. Will the clients be reconnected and resolve it? Should I implement reconnection and tell the broker which messages are currently in progress?

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/persistence-conf.html & https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#durability

Comment: @Alexander Yes I am using durable queues if you are talking about this.

Comment: The question is about what RabbitMQ will do in case of crash with unacknowledged messages.

Comment: Any unacknowledged messages generally get requeued in the event of a crash, but it really depends on your settings.